# Правильное использование союза "а" в сложном предложении

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, запятые, грамматика, союзы

Как будет более корректно использовать союз а в данном предложении? Делить предложение на две части или писать два простых предложения?

- Учеба – это тоже своего рода работа, а любая работа должна
  вознаграждаться
- Учеба – это тоже своего рода работа. А любая работа должна
  вознаграждаться

Это предложение предполагается использовать в заголовке, поэтому ищу наиболее грамотное решение.
Спасибо.

Comment: Хорошо бы дать понять — чем вознаграждается работа. Так чем?

Answer (score 1):

Второй вариант лучше, так как эти предложения довольно самостоятельные и могут существовать отдельно сами по себе.